# org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character on Android

Tags: android, json, facebook-fql

I parse the JSON String and face the error

org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character 25

my JSON is retrieved from Facebook

```
{Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: GraphObject{graphObjectClass=GraphObject, state={"data":[{"venue":{"id":108242939200809,"zip":"","longitude":11.4,"latitude":62.5833,"street":""},"location":"Røros, Norway","eid":1473462312875161,"pic_big":"https:\/\/fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net\/static-ak\/rsrc.php\/v2\/yn\/r\/5uwzdFmIMKQ.png","pic_small":"https:\/\/fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net\/static-ak\/rsrc.php\/v2\/yy\/r\/XcB-JGXohjk.png","description":"Test","name":"Test"},{"venue":{"id":105818232792451,"zip":"","longitude":108.217,"latitude":16.0167,"street":""},"location":"Hòa Vang","eid":1425682134338854,"pic_big":"https:\/\/fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net\/static-ak\/rsrc.php\/v2\/yn\/r\/5uwzdFmIMKQ.png","pic_small":"https:\/\/fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net\/static-ak\/rsrc.php\/v2\/yy\/r\/XcB-JGXohjk.png","description":"test","name":"Test"}]}}, error: null, isFromCache:false}
```

My JSON parser is

```
public static JSONArray parse(Response response) throws JSONException{          
        JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(response.toString());
        return jsonArray;
    }
```

Please help me. Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried using Volley + GSON? It's pretty easy to implement. Check out the tutorial: http://blog.aimanbaharum.com/2014/02/android-development-5-using-volley-and.html

Answer (score 9):

This is, May be because you are trying to parse `response` after coverting your `response` into String with `response.toString()`

So if your `response` is

`{"title":"This is Title","message":"This is message"}`

and you converted it to `String` with `response.toString()`

Then your `response` will be like this

`{title:This is Title,message:This is message}`

So you are trying to parse `response` of type `String` and the compiler will not be able to parse that `response` and it will `throws` an `error` like `Unterminated object at character......`

So make sure that you are parsing valid JSON.

> EDIT ( Credit : [Dhruv Raval](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4025692/dhruv-raval) for [below edited solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33298847/4696610) )

**You may solve this by:**

***Before:***

```
GraphResponse response;
JSONObject jObjResponse = new JSONObject(response.toString());
```

***After:***

```
GraphResponse response;
JSONObject jObjResponse = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response.getJSONObject()));
```

Comment: Please provide the solution to this problem. Thanks!

Comment: @DakshGargas debug the code before parsing JSON and make sure that the JSON is valid ( in this case 'not string' )  and for solution see my updated answer.

Comment: Yeah, I had fixed it... I just added that comment so you can help future visitors.

Comment: Well Thx for that :)

Comment: What would be the solution for this problem in kotlin? I tried String.valueOf but it doesn't exist somehow.

Answer (score 3):

i m getting same error & solving them like:

GraphResponse response;

***Before:***

```
       JSONObject jObjResponse = new JSONObject(response.toString());
```

***After:***

```
JSONObject jObjResponse = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response.getJSONObject()));
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use `JSONObject graphObj =response.getJSONObject();` and you will get the `graphObject`.

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON is invalid.  All variable names need to be quoted.

Comment: Hi Gabe, can you explain more? This is what I get from Facebook. How to correct them? Thank you.

Comment: Notice how all the variable names after state have "" around them?  That's right.  See how the first few don't?  That's invalid.  It causes a crash when you try to parse it, because it doesn't know where the variable name ends without it.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(response.toString());
```

to

```
JSONObject start = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response.getJSONObject()));
```

then direct call

```
 JSONArray data = start.getJSONArray("data");
```

It gives you the "Data" JSON Array.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
            JSONObject jsonData = response.getJSONObject();
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonData.getJSONArray("data");

            Log.e("MainActivity ", "jsondata   -->  " + jsonArray.toString(2));
            Log.e("MainActivity ", "jsonArray.length()->  " + jsonArray.length());

            likesPojos.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                Log.e("MainActivity ", "message  -->  " + json.getString("name"));
                Log.e("MainActivity ", "id  -->  " + json.getString("id"));

                LikesPojo likesPojo = new LikesPojo();
                likesPojo.setId(json.getString("id"));
                likesPojo.setName(json.getString("name"));
                likesPojos.add(likesPojo);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```