# Unterminated object at character 83 of

Tags: android, retrofit

I am using this code to get an object form response,
this is the response :

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "message": "slider_success",
    "success": "success",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "image": "jbk1dahYH3lgKWGlkX2dZCpy46iC5WzIWmiIewz.jpg",
            "body": "details",
            "status": "0",
            "product_id": "0",
            "created_at": "2021-12-29T08:40:53.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-12-29T09:50:12.000000Z"
        }
]
}
```

and I use tins code :

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response.body().toString());
```

and this is the message error :

Unterminated object at character 83 of {code=200.0, message=slider_success, success=success, data=[{id=2.0, image=storage/sliders/tjbk1dahYH3lgKWGlkX2dZCpy46iC5WzIWmiIewz.jpg, body=details, status=0, product_id=0, created_at=2021-12-29T08:40:53.000000Z, updated_at=2021-12-29T09:50:12.000000Z}, {id=1.0, image=storage/sliders/r6aGXzvUEeHhHfc7HERzOyfz2blNr4e7HdbWU8nK.png, body=details, status=0, product_id=0, created_at=2021-12-29T08:40:26.000000Z, updated_at=2021-12-29T09:50:17.000000Z}]}

Comment: Duplicate: [org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368305/org-json-jsonexception-unterminated-object-at-character-on-android)

Comment: that not work with me

Answer (score 1):

If you are using with Retrofit. This code fix my problem:

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(new Gson().toJson(response.body()));
```